# Query NHibernate Cache

Tags: nhibernate, caching

Is there a way to check if an entity is allready in the cache of NHB (no 2nd level cache enabled)
when only the database primary key/Id is known, **without hitting the DB as one would if using Get?**

In short something down the lines of:

```
 _session.ExistsInCache()
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way...

```
var exists = NHibernateUtil.IsInitialized(Session.Load<YourClass>(id));
```